Need Regex Pattern for a form fieldin proper name
I want to create a HTML pattern for a field as (Display name). There isn't any more complex file, just a HTML file with one field.
The requirements are:

The starting character of the field can just be a uppercase letter
and following letters should be lowercase but can be any kind of
characters (number, special character)
Can't start with space and can't use consecutive spaces
Words after space can start with (letter, number, special
character) but if its a letter should be uppercase

I could write the regex expression that match the most of the requirements but special characters aren't being included.
^[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*)*$

but I want to use special characters and numbers anywhere (except the first letter) and problem is happening here, this is the pattern:
^[A-Z][a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`|~]*( [A-Z][a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`|~]*)*$

and I'm getting this error on console:
this causing this error: Unable to check <input pattern=‘^[A-Z][a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^|~]*( [A-Z][a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^|~]*)*$’> because ‘/^[A-Z][a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^|~]*( [A-Z][a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^|~]*)*$/v’ is not a valid regexp: invalid character in class in regular expression

I tried many other things, but using special characters is a troublemaker for me. Would you please tell me what's the correct pattern for it?
Thanks.
This is the whole code:


const registrationForm = document.querySelector('#registration-form');

registrationForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault();  // 4 testing mode
  console.clear();
  console.log( ':) name  accepted ', registrationForm.display_name.value);
  }
<form id="registration-form">
  <!-- Display Name Field -->
  <label for="display-name">Display Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="display-name" name="display_name" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z0-9@()[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+/=?^`|~]*(( [A-Z][a-z0-9@()[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+/=?^`|~]*)| (?! )[a-zA-Z0-9@()[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+/=?^`|~]*)*$" title="Display name must start with a letter, have no consecutive spaces, and each word must start with an uppercase letter. Length must be between 2 and 50 characters."
    minlength="2" maxlength="50" required>
  <br><br>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




Please, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

@GillesQuénot Would you please which part of this question has problem? Because I tried to explain all phases and examples and the problem, and there isn't anything unnecessary in it

Isn't it just something like ^[A-Z]([^ ]| [^ ])*

We need source file or sample to be reproductible and tested

@GillesQuénot Don't have one, just a html file with 1 field, simple as that. i'm just testing, there isn't anything else. so please get back your -1

I didn't voted any -1. We still need a reproductible code. This is the SO rules.

@GillesQuénot is it ok right now? i added the code

is that for a proper name or for filename usage ?

I tried other answers but all of them getting error on browser console, so i found the closest thing to what i wanted and without getting any error:
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\-=\[\]\\\{\}\|;':\,\.\/<>\?]*( (?! )[a-zA-Z0-9~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\-=\[\]\\\{\}\|;':\,\.\/<>\?]*)*$

The only thing i exclude was "

It is not clear what you mean by "special character".
I have chosen to define it as anything that is not: an upper or lower case letter, a digit, or whitespace.
^\p{Lu}[^\p{Lu}\p{Z}]*(?:\p{Z}[^\p{Ll}\p{Z}][^\p{Lu}\p{Z}]*)*$

Just edit the bits between [...] to change the definition to exclude more.
For information on unicode character categories, see:
https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode16.0.0/core-spec/chapter-4/#G124142

I really like your unicode approach! Try to avoid catastrophic backtracking (...*)*. See my answer for a way to avoid this.

@DuesserBaest the bit between parentheses starts with a space and then another character. only the tail is optional. I don't think there should be any backtracking, since space is excluded except as start character

Try:
^[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`|~]|\s[A-Z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`|~])*$

See: regex101

Explanation

^...$: Anchor to ensure whole field is matched
[A-Z]: First upper case letter
(?: ... )*: Then repeat either

[a-z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`|~]: Lower case or special character
|: or
\s[A-Z0-9@()\[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`|~]: Space followed by uppercase or special character




The issue is with the way special characters are escaped and defined in your regular expression. Specifically, the ] character within the character set (enclosed in square brackets []) must be escaped properly because it is a metacharacter that denotes the end of a character set.
Here's the corrected regex:
^[A-Z][a-z0-9@()[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+/=?^`|~]*( [A-Z][a-z0-9@()[\]{}._\-!#$%&'*+/=?^`|~]*)*$


Thanks , but it doesnt meet all requirements,
First Character of each word should be uppercase and following letters of that word should be lower case
The starting character of the field should be just Uppercase letter
No consecutive spaces
First letter of following words can be any kind of characters
using any kind of characters is free except the starting character of the field.
